# ¿Cómo corregir este problema al crear un SP que inserta datos en una tabla? Error code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure, insert

Estoy intentando crear un sp para insertar datos en una tabla, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO cliente ( Id_Cliente, Nombre, DNI,
> telefono, Direccion ) VALUES ( N_' at line 8"

Este es el DDL de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
  `Id_Cliente` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `DNI` int NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Cliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Este es el código en el que me sale error, en la línea del `INSERT INTO`:

```
DELIMITER //
USE NEGOCIO//
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ELIMINACION_DATO (
IN N_Id_Cliente int,
IN N_Nombre VARCHAR (50),
IN N_DNI INT,
IN N_TELEFONO VARCHAR (50),
IN N_DIRECCION VARCHAR (60),
BEGIN
INSERT INTO cliente (
Id_Cliente,
Nombre,
DNI,
telefono,
Direccion
)
VALUES (
N_Id_Cliente,
N_Nombre,
N_DNI,
N_TELEFONO,
N_DIRECCION
)
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. NO GRITES, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenías un par de errores de sintaxis. Prueba así:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ELIMINACION_DATO (
IN N_Id_Cliente int,
IN N_Nombre VARCHAR (50),
IN N_DNI INT,
IN N_TELEFONO VARCHAR (50),
IN N_DIRECCION VARCHAR (60))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO cliente (
Id_Cliente,
Nombre,
DNI,
telefono,
Direccion
)
VALUES (
N_Id_Cliente,
N_Nombre,
N_DNI,
N_TELEFONO,
N_DIRECCION
);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @FranciscoAlonso por favor, haz las aclaraciones añadiendo la info EN la pregunta. Como ves, en los comentarios es casi ilegible e infumable el código.

Comment: @David JP probe de esa forma pero ahora me da error 1064 en la fila del END. que crees que podria estar faltando?

Comment: Supongo que será por los `DELIMITER` prueba como indico en la respuesta que acabo de modificar